# Excel Macro to change cell alignment, borders and wrap text if a value has been entered into another cell in the same row

Tags: excel, alignment, cell, word-wrap, vba

I am trying to create an excel macro which updates the cell alignment, wrap text and borders of cells in each row if a value is entered into one cell within that specific row. For example, if a value is entered into cell A1, then I want the macro to update the wrap text, cell alignment and borders of cells A1:O1. Unfortunately, applying conditional formating to each row within the spreadsheet is rather cumbersome and only will handle updating the cell borders, so I think that a macro that can update all 3 cell formatting elements and dynamically searches the entire worksheet, would be best.

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you want to trigger this macro, nor what exact formatting you want to apply, but here's what I would do:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        With Range(Target, Target.Offset(0,14)
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .WrapText = True
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End with
    end if
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
Add button and Assign Macro window should appear. Select New and put the code there.

```
For Each Target in Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp))
  If Target <> "" Then
     With Range(Target, Target.Offset(0,14)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
     End With
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Just play around with parameters and styles. `.Borders()` refers all borders.

Comment: Awesome! I would like to trigger this macro with a button. If that cannot be done then I would like it to be trigger whenever a change is made to the worksheet...which I think is what you have in the macro that you wrote above. Does this apply if text values are entered into a cell in column 1?

Comment: Ok...after testing it, this does work if text values have been entered. So, now I just want to activate this macro with a command button. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know how to trigger this macro with a command button?

Comment: Thanks, however, for some reason I am getting an "Application defined or Object defined" error and when I click "debug" it is highlighting: For Each Target In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(60000, 1).End(xlTop))

Comment: Typo in End parameter. Should be fine now.